# How to dynamically change the configuration file while using Quick Fix J Engine to receive message?

Tags: java, quickfixj

I have specified host and port in the configuration file manually. All I'm trying is to dynamically change that value in that file or Is there any other alternative option to change the host and port name according to user selection

```
[DEFAULT]# Settings which apply to all the Sessions.
ConnectionType=initiator
LogonTimeout=30
ReconnectInterval=30
ResetOnLogon=Y
FileLogPath=E:\eclipse_kepler\Workspace\FIX_Analyzer\src\simulator\logs.txt
[SESSION]# Settings specifically for one session
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=THIS VALUE IS THE CLIENT ID
TargetCompID=THIS VALUE IS THE FIX SERVER ID
SocketConnectHost=192.168.15.58 
SocketLocalHost=192.168.15.58
StartDay=sunday
EndDay=friday
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
CheckLatency=N
MaxLatency=240
SocketConnectPort=5005
SocketConnectHost=192.168.15.58
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=E:\eclipse_kepler\Workspace\FIX_Analyzer\src\simulator\CustomFix.xml
FileStorePath=C:\Work\QuickFIXJ\sessioninfo
```

Comment: The property `SocketConnectHost` appears twice in your configuration file. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

In the `quickfix` package, the class `SessionSettings` has a constructor to load the configuration file.

Then you should be able to use the set methods to modify what you want.

For example, to change the host only for a specific session:

```
final SessionSettings ss = new SessionSettings( "session.cfg" );

for( final Iterator<SessionID> i = ss.sectionIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    final SessionID id = i.next();
    if( id.getSenderCompID().startsWith("quote") )
        ss.setString( id, "SocketConnectHost", "123.101.202.010" );
}
```